# Send client org data on app install to ISV

Tags: appexchange

When someone installs my app on App Install, I need their Org ID, Account Name, Name, email, & phone of the System Admin. This information will be sent to my org and create/update the account associated with client.

How is it done?

Comment: I am assuming by the question the answer is no but do you use the LMA? If not it can provide a lot of that information although not for the userinfo. You could also do a post install page that sends the infor for the current user although that breaks if the "app takes a long time to install"

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure whether there is a built-in way of doing this. But I searched through internet and documents and didn't see anything. You can still wait to see more to come. But if there is nothing, here is a walkaround.

In your setup/initialize page for your app, in the setup button, add in the functionality to do a callout to your own company's web service. And you can fetch the data via that webservice. If you don't have that setup/init page, you can always make one and use a custom setting to disable your app before they setting it up. Of course, this is only a walkaround. So if there is a native Salesforce way, you can ignore this one.

Comment: I searched as well, nothing. Thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the InstallHandler interface: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm along with an `@future` method to make the call out to your system. Just be sure to follow all SFDC guidelines on which information is OK to capture.

If you have not done so, you will also need to create an endpoint to receive the callout in your Salesforce org. This is a more complicated task but there is tons of documentation out there on creating REST endpoints in Salesforce.